# Searching similar word on MySql

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I've a problem, I need to search into MyISAM FullText field.

What I need to search?

```
ie. "avrir"
ie. "dividdos"
ie. "petacular"
```

What I have in my field's?

```
ie. "abrir"
ie. "divididos"
ie. "espectacular"
```

As you can see in the examples a user can put a wrong word in the search and I need to be able to select the best matching word.

Does anyone have an idea how can I do this?

I read about "[sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)" but I didn't find a solution for this question with.

Comment: How is sphinx: http://sphinxsearch.com/ not working for you, it sounds like the perfect solution, read: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-sphinxsearch/

Comment: As soundex of MySql the sphinxsearch with php doesn't work either cause it uses only russian and english morphology, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can download a levenshtein udf
For info about levenshtein see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

At http://www.joshdrew.com/

Download location:
http://www.joshdrew.com/mysql_levenshtein_udf-1.0.tar.gz

This will allow you to install an UDF that will add a levenshtein function in MySQL that you can use in your queries.
You can compile the UDF **on linux** using the instruction in the .gz file.

Here's how to install the UDF after you've compiled it.

```
>mv mysqllevenshtein.so /usr/lib
```

Then launch mysql

```
>mysql -uroot -pPASS
```

in mysql

```
mysql> use DATABASE
```

> Database changed

```
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein RETURNS INT SONAME 'mysqllevenshtein.so';

select levenshtein(word1,word2) as dist 
from book where ETC........... 
order by dist asc 
limit 0,10;
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it seems to will work fine for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's SOUNDEX() function might help you but it won't work magically with a blob of text in a `FULLTEXT` index.

Levenshtein distance might be something worth looking at too.

Comment: Yes, i've been trying with SOUNDEX() but right now only work with Enlish, and i need to it working with spanish, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can achieve what you want, with that what @Johan suggested. Anyways.

If you want to use sphinx the function you are searching for is called

**stemming**

see the Sphinx Doc for more details

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html

The following is stated in the documentation

- Sphinx supports stemming (stemmers for English, Russian and Czech are 
    built-in; and stemmers for French, Spanish, Portuguese, Italian, 
    Romanian, German, Dutch, Swedish, Norwegian, Danish, Finnish, 
    Hungarian, are available by building third 
    party libstemmer library);

We currently use Sphinx at work and are really happy with it.

Takes some time to get used to it and understand it but once you got
it its hell a lot faster that mysql full-text search.

Regards